# Finding out which card a user clicked on (sprites)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I'm writing a version of the game Memory. I have two groups- one for the "covers" and one for the cards itself. The covers are the ones that go ontop of the cards in order to hide the cards. The problem that I can't figure out is when a user clicks on one of the cards, I used the `kill()` in order to remove the cover card and the card underneath shows (essentially its being flipped), however I can't figure out how to find the position of the card underneath inside the group. How can I find out which card the user clicked on?

Comment: I suggest you replace the title with something like your last sentence.  An index is only one way of identifying a card.  See my answer for another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame mouse clicking detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection)

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on how you display the images.  Here is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses a Button subclass.  This allows instances to carry indentifying information and to use a bound method as the command.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class Card(tk.Button):
    hide = 'XXX'
    def __init__(self, txt):
        super().__init__(root, text=self.hide)
        self.txt = txt
        self.exposed = False
    def flip(self):
        self['text'] = self.hide if self.exposed else self.txt
        self.exposed = not self.exposed

for i, txt in enumerate(('one', 'two')):
    card = Card(txt)
    card['command'] = card.flip
    card.grid(row=0, column=i)

#root.mainloop()  # uncomment if run on command line without -i
```

Comment: Whoops, after posting this answer, I noticed that the tag is `pygame` rather than `tkinter`.  People often use tkinter for card games like this.  I don't know which of the tkinter alternatives can be adapted to pygame.