# Don't stay pressed on left click mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I just wanted to create a little thing that will stop me from clicking more than once on the left mouse button at the same time.

```
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if click[0] == 1:
        print ("lel")
```

In this code, if I stay pressed on my left mouse, it will print out very fast and very much `"lel"`s. I want to only execute the code once at a time so that it won't spam.

Comment: Then set something to determine whether you've already handled a given mouse click.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Thank you ! It works fine now :) ! But why didn't you just answer with the answer button ?

Comment: @Daemond-Creep I am not overly familiar with pygame - little hands-on experience - but I am a game developer in any case. Moved it to an answer instead. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd switch to using `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.wait()` and `print ("lel")` when MOUSEBUTTONUP event is received. That way, you will print "on click" rather than "on held down" which is what is happening to you.

This has been covered here: [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection)