# How to change rect color on mouse click Python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I created a window with a width and height of 800 pixels using pygame then drew rectangles with size 32 to make the window a 25x25 grid. What I want to do is change the color of the rectangle I click to change.

My Code:

```
def createGrid():
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
    BLOCK_SIZE = 32
    WHITE = (255,255,255)

    pygame.init()
    frame = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PathFinder")
    frame.fill(WHITE)
    for y in range(SCREEN_HEIGHT):
            for x in range(SCREEN_WIDTH):
                rect = pygame.Rect(x*BLOCK_SIZE, y*BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE - 1, BLOCK_SIZE - 1)
                pygame.draw.rect(frame, (0,250,0), rect)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() 
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: That question has already been answerd here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection

Comment: use `rect = pygame.Rect(...)` to keep rectangle position (every rectangle need own `rect`). Use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` to recognize mouse click -  and then you can use `rect.colidepoint(event.pos)` to check if you clicked rectangle (you have to use it with every `rect`). And then assing new color to variable which you use to display this rectangle (every rectangle new own variable). And you have to draw rectangles inside `while True`

Comment: Thanks to both. The advice was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create list with all `rects` and they colors.

Next you should draw all rect inside `while` loop.

And finally you have to use `event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to get mouse click and compare mouse position with every `rect` on list and change color on list.

```
import pygame
import sys

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
WHITE = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

frame = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("PathFinder")

# create list with all rects
all_rects = []
for y in range(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, BLOCK_SIZE):
    row = []
    for x in range(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, BLOCK_SIZE):
        rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, BLOCK_SIZE-1, BLOCK_SIZE-1)
        row.append([rect, (0, 255, 0)])            
    all_rects.append(row)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # check which rect was clicked and change its color on list
            for row in all_rects:
                for item in row:
                    rect, color = item
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        if color == (0, 255, 0):
                            item[1] = (255, 0, 0)
                        else:
                            item[1] = (0, 255, 0)

    # draw all in every loop

    frame.fill(WHITE)

    for row in all_rects:
        for item in row:
            rect, color = item
            pygame.draw.rect(frame, color, rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Eventually you could draw all rects before loop and use `event` to draw new rect on clicked rect. But you still need list with all rects to check which rect was click and what is its color.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your code is intended to do? This example shows how to paint to the primary display surface but doesn't keep track of which colour is where.

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

size = 32

pygame.init()
s = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
s.fill(white)

# press escape to exit example
while True:
    e = pygame.event.get()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: break

    x = int(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] / size) * size
    y = int(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] / size) * size

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        pygame.draw.rect(s, red, (x, y, size, size), 0)

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```