# How can I add an image or icon to a button rectangle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am a newbie to Pygame and I have created already the codes for my button but I still have a problem because I don't know how will I put an image instead of the solid color red in a rectangle. Here is my codes, hope you can help!

```py
def button(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            if action == "continue":
                quiz()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, w, h))  
    pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    screen.blit(randomList, [0, 0])
    button(399, 390, 300, 50, red, brightRed, "continue")
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to load an image:

```py
my_image = pygame.image.load('my_image.png').convert_alpha()
```

And `blit` it an top of the rectangle:

```py
def button(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, img, imgon, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
    on_button = rect.collidepoint(mouse)
    if on_button:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, rect)
        screen.blit(imgon, imgon.get_rect(center = rect.center))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, rect)
        screen.blit(img, img.get_rect(center = rect.center))

    if on_button:  
        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            if action == "continue":
                quiz()

image = pygame.image.load('my_image.png').convert_alpha()
imageOn = pygame.image.load('my_image_on.png').convert_alpha()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    screen.blit(randomList, [0, 0])
    button(399, 390, 300, 50, red, brightRed, image, imageOn, "continue")
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

---

In pygame a button is nothing more than a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. It is completely irrelevant whether a text or an image is on the button. I recommend to represent the buttons by [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects.

See also [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection/64533684#64533684) respectively [Mouse](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_mouse_and_mosuse_events.md) and [Sprite](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md).

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):
        super().__init__() 
        img = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((70, 70))
        self.original_image.blit(img, img.get_rect(center = self.original_image.fill((127, 127, 127)).center))
        self.hover_image = pygame.Surface((70, 70))
        self.hover_image.blit(img, img.get_rect(center = self.hover_image.fill((228, 228, 228)).center))
        self.image = self.original_image 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.hover = False

    def update(self):
        self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        self.image = self.hover_image if self.hover else self.original_image

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

group = pygame.sprite.Group([
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() // 3, window.get_height() // 3, 'Apple64.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() * 2 // 3, window.get_height() // 3, 'Banana64.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() // 3, window.get_height() * 2 // 3, 'Pear64.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() * 2// 3, window.get_height() * 2 // 3, 'Plums64.png'),
])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    group.update()

    window.fill(0)
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @annyeongkre I've changed the answer. If you don't want to draw the rectangle, then skip `pygame.draw.rect(...)`

Comment: @annyeongkre You can invoke `button` 4 times with different paramters.

Comment: @annyeongkre Sorry, but that's far over the original question and can't be answered in a short comment. The comment section is not intended to ask additional questions. You have to [Ask a new public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)