# How to check if a button is clicked in pygame

Tags: pygame, python-3.8

I am making a spaceship game where you fire bullets at enemy spaceships and collect coins. When you click the start button, the game is supposed to start. However, when I try clicking the start button, the game doesn't start! Is something wrong with my if statement to identify if the start button is clicked?

This is my current code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint, choice
from tools import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

SCREEN_X = 800
SCREEN_Y = 500
CENTER_POS = (400, 225)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y))


class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A spaceship object. Used for the player."""

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (175, 175))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        """Updates the spaceship rect"""
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A bullet object. Appears when the player clicks."""

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        """Let's the bullet move upward."""

        self.y -= 5
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """An enemy object. The player's job is to destroy enemies."""

    def __init__(self, s, x, y, t):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.type = t
        self.screen, self.x, self.y = s, x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load(get_enemy_image()[self.type])

        # There is an if statement because the
        # N1 Galaxy Fighter and M7 Comet Glider need different sizes

        if self.type == "N1 Galaxy Fighter":
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (235, 215))
        elif self.type == "M7 Comet Glider":
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (155, 215))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.score_given = get_enemy_given_score()[self.type]

    def update(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()
        self.y += 3
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class GameOverBackground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """The game over background object."""

    def __init__(self, s, x, y, size=(100, 100)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen, self.x, self.y = s, x, y
        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Game_Over.jpg")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def blitme(self):
        """Blits the game over image on the screen"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Coin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A coin object."""

    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 100)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.x, self.y = pos[0], pos[1]
        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.image.load("coin.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        """Updates the coin rect"""
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class StartButton(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, s, x, y, size=None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("start_button.png")

        if size is not None:
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, size)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


bg = GameOverBackground(screen, 0, 0, size=(800, 500))

spaceship = Spaceship(screen, 400, 400)

start_button = StartButton(screen, CENTER_POS[0], CENTER_POS[1], size=(300, 195))
game_started = False

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
coins = pygame.sprite.Group()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

enemy_interval = 2000
enemy_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(enemy_event, enemy_interval)

coin_interval = 3500
coin_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(coin_event, coin_interval)

score = 0
lives = 3

with open("high_score.txt", "r") as file:
    highscore = file.read()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
score_text_surface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
lives_text_surface = font.render("HP: %s" % lives, True, (0, 0, 0))
high_score_text_surface = font.render("High score: %s" % highscore, True, (0, 0, 0))

spaceship_collided = False

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if game_started and event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet(screen, spaceship.x, spaceship.y - 20)
            bullets.add(bullet)

        if game_started and event.type == enemy_event and not lives <= 0:
            enemy = Enemy(screen, randint(-100, 725), 0, choice(["N1 Galaxy Fighter", "M7 Comet Glider"]))
            enemies.add(enemy)

        if game_started and event.type == coin_event and not lives <= 0:
            if len(coins) < 100:
                coins.add(Coin((randint(-125, 750), randint(-200, 400))))

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # DO NOT DRAW ANYTHING IN FRONT OF THIS LINE, I'M WARNING YOU

    if not game_started:
        start_button.blitme()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if CENTER_POS[0] < mouse_pos[0] < CENTER_POS[0]+250 and CENTER_POS[1] > mouse_pos[1] > CENTER_POS[1] + 460:
            game_started = True
    else:
        bullets.update()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        amount = 5

        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            spaceship.x -= amount
        elif key[pygame.K_d]:
            spaceship.x += amount
        elif key[pygame.K_w]:
            spaceship.y -= amount
        elif key[pygame.K_s]:
            spaceship.y += amount

        spaceship.update()

        if not lives <= 0:
            screen.blit(spaceship.image, spaceship.rect)

        if not lives <= 0:
            bullets.draw(screen)
            enemies.draw(screen)

            coins.update()
            coins.draw(screen)

            for i in enemies:
                i.update()
                if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(i, bullets, True):
                    score += i.score_given
                    i.kill()

        if spaceship_collided and lives <= 0:
            bg.blitme()
            if score > int(highscore):
                with open("high_score.txt", "w") as file:
                    file.write(str(score))

        if score >= 99999:
            score = 99999

        if not lives <= 0:
            score_text_surface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(score_text_surface, (590, 0))

            lives_text_surface = font.render("HP: %s" % lives, True, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(lives_text_surface, (260, 0))

            high_score_text_surface = font.render("High score: %s" % highscore, True, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(high_score_text_surface, (360, 0))

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True):
            lives -= 1
            spaceship_collided = True

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, coins, dokill=True):
            score += 10

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and the method [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

```py
button_rect = start_button.image.get_rect(topleft = (start_button.x, start_button.y))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if not game_started: 
                if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    game_started = True

            else:
                bullet = Bullet(screen, spaceship.x, spaceship.y - 20)
                bullets.add(bullet)
```

See [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection/64533684#64533684)

Comment: Wait, why is the start button not showing up even when I add this:

 if not game_started:
        start_button.blitme()

Comment: @DavidBagel Why did you delete `start_button.blitme()`?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I deleted that accidentally.