# How do I add a border to a sprite when the mouse hovers over it, and delete it after the mouse stops?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a sprite, and I want it to be so that when the mouse hovers over it, it places a small border around the sprite, and when it leaves, delete that border. How would I go about doing this?

Sprite Class:

```
class textureblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, imagefile):
    super(textureblock, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load(imagefile).convert_alpha()
    self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (48,48))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
  def die(self):
    self.kill()
```

I can add more code if required.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the image and draw a rectangle around it:

```py
self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (48,48))
self.hover_surf = self.surf.copy()
pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_surf, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_surf.get_rect(), 6)
```

Check if the mouse is on the image with [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) and select the image:

```py
self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
self.image = self.hover_surf if self.hover else self.surf
```

This all is explained in the answers to the question [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection/64533684#64533684).

Also note that [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The *Surface* is placed at a position on the display with the `blit` function.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, either by a keyword argument, e.g:

```py
self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

Store the mouse position in an attribute of the object. `kill` the *Sprite* when the mouse hovers over the *Sprite* and the mouse position does not change for som frames (e.g. 10):

```py
class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):
        # [...]

        self.hover = False
        self.mouse_pos = None
self.count = 0

    def update(self):
        # [...]

        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos:
            self.count += 1
            if self.count > 10:
              self.kill()
        else:
            self.count = 0
        self.mouse_pos = mouse_pos
```

---

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import pygame

class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):
        super().__init__() 
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.hover_image = self.original_image.copy()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (255, 255, 0), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 6)
        self.image = self.original_image 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.hover = False
        self.mouse_pos = None
        self.count = 0

    def update(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.hover = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        self.image = self.hover_image if self.hover else self.original_image
        if self.hover and mouse_pos == self.mouse_pos:
            self.count += 1
            if self.count > 10:
              self.kill()
        else:
            self.count = 0
        self.mouse_pos = mouse_pos

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

group = pygame.sprite.Group([
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() // 3, window.get_height() // 3, 'Apple.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() * 2 // 3, window.get_height() // 3, 'Banana.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() // 3, window.get_height() * 2 // 3, 'Pear.png'),
    SpriteObject(window.get_width() * 2// 3, window.get_height() * 2 // 3, 'Plums.png'),
])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    group.update()

    window.fill(0)
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @Samuel [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) *"remove the Sprite from all Groups"*. You have to use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and `pygame.sprite.Group` interact together.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I see ```window.fill(0)``` and it draws the sprites using the group. I tried this, the frame rate dropped though, probably from the constant clearing.

Comment: @Samuel The frame rate drops when you load the images in  every frame. Load the images only once (`pygame.image.load`). What is your frame rate?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! I’ll try that later.

Comment: Is it possible to change the image to just a filled square? I tried doing ```self.image = self.image.fill((0,191,255))```, but I got ```TypeError: Source objects must be a surface```

Comment: @Samuel Both images or just the image with the border?

Comment: If you just want a filled square you have to create a _Surface_ with a certain size: `self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))`. You can fill an existing _Surface_ with `self.image.fill((0,191,255))` (no `self.image =`).

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I will try that.