# Check if mouse pointer touching any rectangles created using for loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently creating a minesweeper game and my code looks something like this (for creating the rectangles). I've already created a list of every rectangle and their coordinates but there's one thing I now need. I need to know if the mouse pointer clicks on a rectangle (and which rectangle - each will have different information). When it clicks on one, it will check if that one has a bomb.

```
for i in range(1,boardSquaresY):
    global rectList
    for x in range(1,boardSquaresX):
        pygame.draw.rect(display,gray,pygame.Rect(squareX*x,squareY,tileSize,tileSize))
        rectList.append(Rect(squareX*x,squareY,tileSize,tileSize))
        print(rectList)
        for stroke in range(4):
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(squareX*x-2, squareY-2, tileSize + 2, tileSize + 2), 1)
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (220, 220, 220), pygame.Rect(squareX * x - 4, squareY - 4, tileSize + 2, tileSize + 2), 1)
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (150, 150, 150), pygame.Rect(squareX * x - 4, squareY - 4, tileSize + 0.5, tileSize + 1), 1)
    squareY += 50
```

Full code below (currently) - only done UI so far.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
#Beginner has a 9x9 board and 10 mines
rectList = []
def Main():
    pygame.init()

    display = pygame.display.set_mode((850,600),0,32)

    white = (255,255,255)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    gray = (220,220,220)
    display.fill(white)

    squareX = 50
    squareY = 50
    tileSize = 50
    boardSquaresX = 10
    boardSquaresY = 10
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(mouse)

    for i in range(1,boardSquaresY):
        global rectList
        for x in range(1,boardSquaresX):
            pygame.draw.rect(display,gray,pygame.Rect(squareX*x,squareY,tileSize,tileSize))
            rectList.append(Rect(squareX*x,squareY,tileSize,tileSize))
            print(rectList)
            for stroke in range(4):
                pygame.draw.rect(display, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(squareX*x-2, squareY-2, tileSize + 2, tileSize + 2), 1)
                pygame.draw.rect(display, (220, 220, 220), pygame.Rect(squareX * x - 4, squareY - 4, tileSize + 2, tileSize + 2), 1)
                pygame.draw.rect(display, (150, 150, 150), pygame.Rect(squareX * x - 4, squareY - 4, tileSize + 0.5, tileSize + 1), 1)
        squareY += 50
    while True:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mouse[0]
        if squareX * x + tileSize > mouse[0] > squareX * x - tileSize and squareY + tileSize > mouse[1] > squareY - tileSize:
            print(mouse)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
Main()
rectList = []
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know the row and column, you just need to test if the mouse is in the rectangle and calculate the row and column using the `//` (floor division) operator:

```py
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
gridRect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, boardSquaresX*tileSize, boardSquaresY*tileSize)
if gridRect.collidePoint(mouse):
    row = mouse[0] // tileSize
    col = mouse[1] // tileSize
```

If you want to find the *Rect* object in the list, you can use [`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

```py
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
muoseRect = pygame.Rect(mouse[0], mouse[1], 1, 1)
index = muoseRect.collidelist(rectList):
if index >= 0:
    rect = rectList[index]
    row = rect.x // tileSize
    col = rect.y // tileSize
```

See also [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907) and [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection/64533684#64533684).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
grid = []
for y in range(5):
    grid.append([])
    for x in range(5):
        grid[y].append(0)

rectangle_size = 100

while True:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[y])):
            if y * rectangle_size < mouse_pos[0] < y * rectangle_size + 50:
                if x * rectangle_size < mouse_pos[1] < x * rectangle_size + 50:
                    print(f"{y}, {x}")
```

Example:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random


pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("hub")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

grid = []
for y in range(5):
    grid.append([])
    for x in range(5):
        grid[y].append((random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))

rect_size = 100

while True:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[y])):

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, grid[y][x], (y * rect_size, x * rect_size, rect_size, rect_size))

            if y * rect_size < mouse_pos[0] < y * rect_size + 50:
                if x * rect_size < mouse_pos[1] < x * rect_size + 50:
                    print(f"{y}, {x}")
    pygame.display.update()
```