# My pygame timer keeps resetting after I hit a target in my aim game

Tags: python, pygame, timer, pygame-clock, pygame-tick

I am trying to make an aim game where a target pops up and once the player clicks on it, the target vanishes and a new one appears in a random location, I want it so that there is a 10 second timer but it keeps going back to 10 each time a target is "hit"

```py
import pygame, random as r, time
FPS = 60
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
WHITE = 255,255,255
BG = 26,26,26
RANGEXMIN = 20
RANGEXMAX = 840
RANGEYMIN = 20
RANGEYMAX = 440
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
tick = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(tick,1000)
pygame.font.init()
FONT = pygame.font.Font('slkscr.ttf', 50)  

    
def aim_train():
    def new_target(countdown,text):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        x = r.randint(RANGEXMIN, RANGEXMAX)
        y = r.randint(RANGEYMIN, RANGEYMAX)
        hit = False
        while not hit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():            
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                    if event.type == tick:
                        countdown= countdown - 1
                        text = str(countdown)
            clock.tick(FPS)
            window.fill(BG)
            timer = FONT.render(text, False, WHITE)
            window.blit(timer, (435, 20))
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pos_x = pos[0]
            pos_y = pos[1]
            target = pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, (x,y,50,50))
            cursor_outline = pygame.draw.circle(window, BG, (pos_x,pos_y), 11)
            cursor = pygame.draw.circle(window, WHITE,(pos_x,pos_y) ,10)
            hit = (pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and target.colliderect(cursor_outline))
            pygame.display.update()
            
    run = True
    countdown = 10
    text = str(countdown)
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        window.fill(BG)
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        new_target(countdown,text)
    pygame.quit()
        
aim_train()
```

The variable "counter" somehow gets reset back to 10 after ever successful hit on a target

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 countdown variables, one in the `new_target` function and one in the `aim_train` function. If you change the variable `countdown` in the `new_target` function, this will not change the variable `countdown` in the `aim_train` function. You must return the new value of countdown from the `new_target` function:

```py
def aim_train():
    def new_target(countdown):
        # [...]

        while not hit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():            
                
                # [...]
                elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                    if event.type == tick:
                        countdown= countdown - 1
            
            # [...]

        return countdown
            
    run = True
    countdown = 10
    while run:
        # [...]

        countdown = new_target(countdown)
```

---

However, I suggest that you restructure your code. Do not use nested application loops. Also see [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection):

```py
import pygame, random as r

FPS = 60
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
WHITE = 255,255,255
BG = 26,26,26
RANGEXMIN = 20
RANGEXMAX = 840
RANGEYMIN = 20
RANGEYMAX = 440
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
tick = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(tick,1000)
pygame.font.init()
FONT = pygame.font.Font('slkscr.ttf', 50)  

def new_target():
    x = r.randint(RANGEXMIN, RANGEXMAX)
    y = r.randint(RANGEYMIN, RANGEYMAX)
    return x, y
    
def aim_train():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    run = True
    countdown = 10
    hits = 0
    countdownSurf = FONT.render(f'time {countdown}', False, WHITE)
    hitsSurf = FONT.render(f'hits {hits}', False, WHITE)
    target = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    target.center = new_target()
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == tick:
                countdown -= 1
                countdownSurf = FONT.render(f'time {countdown}', False, WHITE)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                if target.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    target.center = new_target()
                    hits += 1
                    hitsSurf = FONT.render(f'hits {hits}', False, WHITE)

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.fill(BG)
        window.blit(countdownSurf, countdownSurf.get_rect(center = (300, 45)))
        window.blit(hitsSurf, hitsSurf.get_rect(center = (600, 45)))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, target)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, BG, pos, 11)
        pygame.draw.circle(window, WHITE, pos, 10)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
        
aim_train()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a seperate function, `new_target`, for each target.

The `countdown` variable is defined inside the scope of the function `aim_train`. Because the `new_target` function is defined inside the `aim_train` function, it is a nested function and it can use all the variables that are defined inside `aim_train`. However, the `new_target` function still has its own scope. It can make changes to any variables defined inside `aim_train`, but those changes remain in its own scope. When a call of `new_target` is ended, its scope is discarded and all changes to the variables of `aim_target` are undone. This causes the `countdown` variable to be reset every in new call of `new_target` and thus every time a new target is created.

You might also have noticed that you can't close your window. The window doesn't react to clicking the red cross. This is because the same applies to the `run` variable. When you click the red cross, the `run` variable is set to `True` inside `new_target`, but not in the scope of `aim_train`. As such, the main loop in `aim_train` is not quitted and the program continues.

As a solution to this problem, I would recommend to include all the code of `new_target` into the `aim_train` function. Then you only have one function, which makes that all changes to variables are in the same scope and no changes are discarded:

```py
import pygame, random as r, time
pygame.init()
FPS = 60
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
WHITE = 255,255,255
BG = 26,26,26
RANGEXMIN = 20
RANGEXMAX = 840
RANGEYMIN = 20
RANGEYMAX = 440
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
tick = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(tick,1000)
pygame.font.init()
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
    
def aim_train():
    run = True
    hit = False
    
    countdown = 10
    text = str(countdown)
    
    x = r.randint(RANGEXMIN, RANGEXMAX)
    y = r.randint(RANGEYMIN, RANGEYMAX)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)#switched
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == tick: #changed
                countdown= countdown - 1
                text = str(countdown)
        
        window.fill(BG)
        timer = FONT.render(text, False, WHITE)
        window.blit(timer, (435, 20))
        
        
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pos_x = pos[0]
        pos_y = pos[1]

        target = pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, (x,y,50,50))
        cursor_outline = pygame.draw.circle(window, BG, (pos_x,pos_y), 11)
        cursor = pygame.draw.circle(window, WHITE,(pos_x,pos_y) ,10)
        
        hit = (pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and target.colliderect(cursor_outline))
        if hit:
            hit = False
            x = r.randint(RANGEXMIN, RANGEXMAX)
            y = r.randint(RANGEYMIN, RANGEYMAX)
        pygame.display.update()
        
    pygame.quit()
        
aim_train()
```

Apart from fixing the problem, I have also restructured your code a bit and did the following changes:

- I have changed:

  ```py
  elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
      if event.type == tick:
  ```

  into:

  ```py
  elif event.type == tick:
  ```

  Outside of the `aim_train` function, you have stated that `tick` and `pygame.USEREVENT` are equal. As such, it is useless to compare to them two times, because if the first check is true, then the second one will certainly be.
- I've placed `pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)` outside of the main loop.

  Calling the function sets the mouse invisible untill another call changes sets the mouse back to visible. As such, it is useless to call it multiple times in the loop.

Comment: This is not a mouse click detection, but a mouse press and hold detection.

Comment: The question was not about mouse click detection, but about why the countdown timer resets. And the difference between both doesn't really matter, because you're very likely to have to click on a different spot after you've hit the target.

Comment: Does an answer always have to be completely new before it should be posted? If that was true, only the first one to post an answer would be allowed to answer a lot of the SO questions, which would be an extreme version of [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite).

Comment: It is also not true that my answer only contains information from your answer: Your answer doesn't tell anything about the window not being closable and explains in less detail why there are two different countdown variables.

Comment: Fair enough. In my solution the window is also closeable, but you took more effort to add details in the explanation.