# Python pygame pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] responses when i move mouse, not when the mouse is in the same position

Tags: python, pygame

Im making a 2d game where you can shoot, so the logic is when `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]` (mouse is pressed) bullets are created. Problem is, when im holding my finger on mouse, and key is pressed, my code creates one bullet when i start clicking, when im still clicking nothings happening, when i move my mouse, the bullets start to create. Pygame dont create bullets when the mouse is in a single position, i have to move mouse. Whats wrong. Here is the important fragment of code. (its in a def run())

its in a loop
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y86f.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is not an event, but returns the current state of the button. You have to use the `MOSUEDOWN` event. See [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection)

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is not an event, but returns the current state of the button. You have to use the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`  event. See also [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection).
[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down. If you just want to detect when the mouse button is pressed or released, then you have to implement the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print("clicked", event.button)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            print("released", event.button)
```